# IE not displaying content of table UL

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, browser, mozilla

The UL area is left blank in IE and it displays content fine in Chrome, Firefox and safari.

//on view source in IE am able to see the following code but the ul area is empty in browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">

            <div id="table">
                <center>
                    <ul>                           
                            <li onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" onclick = "descriptionPage('Drinks','Frappuccino');"><p  class="Quor_Widget_item_nameIndex">Frappuccino </p> 
                                <p class="item_priceIndex">$2.50</p></li>


                            <li onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" onclick = "descriptionPage('Drinks','Latte');"><p  class="Quor_Widget_item_nameIndex">Latte </p>
                                <p class="tem_priceIndex">$2.50</p></li>


                    </ul>

                </center>



            </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Please, please, format your code decently before posting it.  Please.

Comment: @Joe Am sorry.. Edited it to be fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul>

                            <li onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" onclick = "descriptionPage('Drinks','Coffee');"><p  class="Quor_Widget_item_nameIndex">Coffee  
                                <p class="Quor_Widget_item_priceIndex">$2.50</p></li>
```

You're opening two `<p>` tags but only closing one in every `<li></li>` pair. Chrome and firefox are smart and they fix this, IE is dumb. Damn is dumb.

P.S. You should format your code.

Edit: there is also a missing `</div>`, you see? Please check that you are closing all your tags.

Comment: Indeeed, this is probably the issue.

Comment: I did formatted my code and closed <P> tag in every <li> , but the issue still continues,

Comment: actaully, there appear to be two div tags that aren't closed

Comment: Fine, Thanx loadz for your suggestion. I will review my code.